# Scale-based Sizing for Hatch Fill in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro

In ArcGIS Pro I'm trying to implement scale-based sizing on a hatch fill of a polygon. I simply want the line width of the hatch to change as you zoom in. The polygon is Single Symbol, parameters as in the pictures.

I am able to do it for the outline (and for various other vector layers in this project) but not for the hatch fill.

Any advice?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the hatch lines width is adjusting automaticaly/lineary based on the scale level..

Answer (score 1):

They will be adjusting automatically based on the scale level, just make sure no reference scale is set on the map

Answer (score 0):

Maybe setting a reference scale for your map could be a workaround.

[ArcGIS Pro Documentation - Map reference scales](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/properties/map-reference-scales.htm)